# When use reverse array with little endian or big endian

Tags: c#, endianness

If I have the array of byte :

```
byte [] a=new byte [4]{0,0,0,1};
```

Is this sequence of data 0001 is Little endian or big endian? And when  I need to reverse array

with  Little endian or big endian?

The architecture of my computer  is Littleendian

Comment: If your desired 32-bit value is `1`, it's stored as big endian.

Comment: i must make reverse for array to store result as big endian=1??

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, bytes don't have an endian order.  Only value type values of a type that requires *more* than a byte for storage can be affected, a byte[] is unambiguous.  You only ever have an issue you try to convert the byte[] to another type with BitConverter.  Given the scarcity of big-endian machines today, you'd better start with {1, 0, 0, 0} if an int value of 1 is intended.

Answer (score 0):

That would be in little-endian representation, as the smallest component is at the end.

You can use the `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property to dynamically find out the endianess of the system that the program is  running on:

```
if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
  Array.Reverse(a);
}
```

Comment: @user2839704: That's unusual as it would change the representation to the one that your system can't use, but in that case just remove the `!` operator from the code.